# How does the InputFile function in R working

Tags: r, amazon-s3, shiny, shinyapps

I am developing an R shiny App, and the app will receive video from the user and upload to AWS s3 bucket. I am not clear about how does this video been uploaded if I use R connect to deploy the app. Does it go through https or http? I know it will be saved to the R shiny server and then upload to s3 bucket but if there is a way to directly save the video to s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

From my own research, the caveat I have found is that you must use the writeBin() function on your upload file, saving it in a temporary directory, before saving it in the aws.s3 bucket.